# How do I change the From address in Outlook to a domain I own?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I'm using Exchange 2010 with Outlook 2010 and I accept email at several different domains. When i send emails they are always sent from my default domain. Is it possible to send from one of the other domains?

I tried enabling the From button in Outlook and typing in the address I want to send from. When I press enter the from address is still listed with the default domain.

Comment: Is Outlook setup for multiple accounts of the other domains? Or are the emails forwarded to the default account you have setup? If setup for multiple accounts, the account should be selectable when you click FROM. The FROM button only works with multiple accounts being setup in Outlook.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to add separate accounts. I've been experimenting with using Send As groups in Exchange as well as adding aliases to a user's email addresses. Although Send As groups seem to work they make the GAL ugly (hiding the groups from the GAL caused them to stop working).